# How to specify different API urls in vue.js for my computer, coworker's computer, and production?

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to have the URL to my api / backend server automatically be loaded and used in all the requests that my vue.js application makes.

For my own laptop, I'm usually running the backend at localhost, so I'd like the url to be localhost.

But on production, and on my coworker's computer, I'd like the production URL to be used (or a staging URL for coworker's computer).

This is because coworker isn't running the backend locally.

Can this be achieved with vue.js?

Comment: "I'd like to have the URL to my api / backend server automatically be loaded"

What do you mean loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [environment variables and modes for vue cli 3](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html); Essentially set up two `.env` files for development and production separately (`.env.development` and `.env.production`):

In `.env.development`, where each developer can set up the base url differently:

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URI=localhost:8000 or a staging uri for your coworker
```

In `.env.production`:

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URI=YourProductionURL
```

And in your app, configure the http request to use `process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URI` as the base URL.

And now when you and your coworker are in the development mode (i.e. running `npm run serve`), it will pick the `VUE_APP_BASE_URI` from `.env.development`; And when it's deployed to production via `npm run build`, your app will use `VUE_APP_BASE_URI` from `.env.production` file.

Comment: So we both need different env.development files? Thanks.

Comment: I believe so if both of you want to develop with `npm run serve` but want to use different base URL. And in this case, a `.env.development.local` file could be more appropriate since it's ignored by git, and you don't have to switch the url back and forth.